# LWC component not showing desired result getting printed empty

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, lwc-wire-adapter

I created a LWC component for a Donation Tracking app that should print in a list all the donors with their total Donations on the Home page and App page.
But in the result an empty lwc component is printed like:

My sfdx code is :

// LWC JavaScript

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecords } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import DONOR_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Donor__c.Name';
import DONOR_DONATION from '@salesforce/schema/Donor__c.Total_Donations__c';
import getAllDonors from '@salesforce/apex/GetDonorsCls.getDonors';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    
const FIELDS = ["Donor__c.Name", "Donor__c.Total_Donations__c"];

export default class DonorAndDonationsSum extends LightningElement {
    donorIds = [];

    @wire(getAllDonors)
    wiredDonors({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            // Extract the IDs from the data
            this.donorIds = data.map(donor => donor.Id);
            console.log(this.donorIds);
        } else if (error) {
            // Handle error
            this.handleError(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getRecords,
       { records:[
            { 
            recordIds: '$donorIds',
            fields: [DONOR_NAME,DONOR_DONATION],
            
            },
           
        
                 ],
        })  
    donors;
    

    handleError(error) {
        // Log the error to the browser's console
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);

        // Display a toast notification with the error message
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error',
            message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.',
            variant: 'error',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="DonorAndDonations">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">      
        <template if:true={donors.data}>
            <ul class="slds-list_dotted">
                <template for:each={donors.data.results} for:item="donor">
                    
                    <li key={donor.Id} >
                        <p>
                            
                            <strong>{donor.result.fields.Name.displayValue}</strong> - {donor.result.fields.Total_Donations__c.displayValue} Total Donations
                        </p>
                        
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </template>
        <template if:true={donors.error}>
            <p>No donors found...</p>
        </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

And the apex class which is querying all the ids of Donor__c object is

```
 public with sharing class GetDonorsCls {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Donor__c> getDonors() {
            if(Schema.SObjectType.Donor__c.isAccessible()){
                return [SELECT Id FROM Donor__c];
            }
            else {
                return new List<Donor__c>();
            }
        
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is causing the error whether it is the SOQL query in Apex class or wire decorator use.

I have a dev org and is the System Administrator profile.

Please help me in solving this.

Regards

Comment: Please read why [you should not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) then edit the question adding the relevant code snippets (please add the whole JS file). In the [Markdown help page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) you can see how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

`for:each={donors.data.records}` should be `for:each={donors.data.results}`, and for each donor, the values would be accessed through `result`, e.g. `{donor.result.fields.Name.displayValue}`.

As a side note, you're already calling `getDonors` in Apex, so it would make more sense to just return the field values you need directly instead of using two round-trips to the server, which is less efficient.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox,Even after updatting the code with the suggested changes Still the output is similar.Here the markup that I changed:<template for:each={donors.data.results} for:item="donor">
                    
                    <li key={donor.Id} >
                        <p>
                            
                            <strong>{donor.result.fields.Name.displayValue}</strong> - {donor.result.fields.Total_Donations__c.displayValue} Total Donations
                        </p>
                        
                    </li>
                </template>